# sql server - Xquery on xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

Hi I am just stuck at finding a right answer and how to do what I am trying to do , Please Can someone help in helping me.

I have the following xml file , which has been generated by a third party, and is held in a table attribute.

```
<a1:RequestWrapper xmlns:a2="http://www.xyz.co.uk/schemas"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:a1="http://www.xyz.co.uk/schemas/services" Type="RequestWrapper">
<a3:request xmlns:a3="http://www.xyz.co.uk/schemas/serialize" Type="Client.DataTransfer.DataImport"> 
 <instructions> 
   <DataImport> 
     <ImportPackage>{ddeae592-309b-47ae-9ee2-0e8a0217a8d4}</ImportPackage> 
     <ImportFile>I:\Funds\Completed\2013\MAY\MAy 28 - 30\Real Engagement.csv</ImportFile> 
     <TruncateStrings>False</TruncateStrings> 
    </DataImport> 
 </instructions> 
  <importTable>Import20130528_154743_156</importTable> 
</a3:request> 
<a1:plan Type="ExecutionPlan"> 
  <deu>2013-05-28T17:40:00.0000000</deu> 
  <ref>Import20130528_154743_156</ref>       
</a1:plan>  
</a1:RequestWrapper>
```

I want to write a Xquery to get the Value Against ImportFile NODE..

I have tried saying

```
    declare @xml xml
    Select @xml = data.xml from Queued_works where referencename = 'ImportFile'

    Select @xml.value('a1/a3/instructions/dataimport/Importfile'),'varchar(100)')
```

But that gives a error, I have tried other ways too but I simply cant get it to work.

Any help please .
Thanks

Comment: FYI these docs on xQuery -- useful when I needed them, but hard to find:  http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/F/B/0FBFAA46-2BFD-478F-8E56-7BF3C672DF9D/XQuery%20Language%20Reference.pdf

Comment: Hi marc_s , I am not getting any error, I just get a Null value . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **respect** the XML namespaces in your XML !

Try this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.xyz.co.uk/schemas/services' AS a1, 
                    'http://www.xyz.co.uk/schemas/serialize' AS a3)
SELECT
    data.xml.value('(/a1:RequestWrapper/a3:request/instructions/DataImport/ImportFile)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM
    dbo.Queued_works
WHERE
    referencename = 'ImportFile'
```

That should grab the contents of the `<ImportFile>` node from your XML and return it as a `Varchar(100)` value.

Comment: THank you so much, it works. as you said I shud have thought about the namespaces.